# Bass' paper on Gorenstein rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, projective-module, proof-explanation, gorenstein

I am currently reading the paper [On the ubiquity of Gorenstein rings](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01112819#page-1) by Hyman Bass.
I found difficulty to understand the proof of Proposition (7.2).

 Under the the following setting:

$A$: commutative Noetherian ring with Krull $\dim A\leq1$, no nilpotent elements

$A'$: integral closure of $A$ is a finitely generated $A$-module

$K$: $S^{-1}A$ where $S=\{$non zero divisor in $A\}$

$M$: f.g. $A$-module

Suppose $M\neq 0$ is reflexive $A$-module. Then either $M$ has a nonzero projective direct summand or else $M$ is an $A_1$-module for some $A\subsetneq A_1 \subset A'$.


The proof is quite long. Part that I don't understand is when the writer tried to use Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Could somebody point out for me on what object shall I apply Chinese Reminder Theorem?